# How do I say ptr+1=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int)); correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I am a beginner in C, and I just started learning memory management and pointers. I know the basics of both, so I first do this:

```
int *ptr; 
ptr=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
```

and then I want to do this:

```
ptr+1=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
```

but I keep getting this error: `[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. How do I write the above line correctly? Thank you in advance. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *ptr,number_of_elems=1;
    
int i;
int b;
int main()
{
    
    ptr=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    int a=1;
    ptr=&a;
    char action[6]; /*add/remove*/
    while(1){
        scanf("%s", &action);
        if(action == "add"){
            number_of_elems+=1;
            ptr+number_of_elems -1=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
            scanf("%d", &b);
            ptr+number_of_elems -1=&b;
            for(int i=0;i<number_of_elems;i++){
                printf("%d\n",ptr+i);
            }
        }
        else if(action=="remove"){
            number_of_elems-=1;
            free(ptr+number_of_elems-1);
            for(int i=0;i<number_of_elems;i++){
                printf("%d\n",ptr+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to do this without memory management. This is the working code I am trying to convert to using `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int array[50];
int newElem;
int lastElem=0;
array[0]=1;
char action; /*a/r     a stand for add and r for remove*/

    while(1){
    scanf("%c", &action);
    
    if(action == 'a'){
        lastElem+=1;
        scanf("%d", &newElem);
        array[lastElem]=newElem;
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<lastElem+1;i++){
            printf("%d",array[i]);
              printf("%c",' ');

        }
    }
    if(action=='r'){
        lastElem-=1;
        free(&array[lastElem]);
        for(int i=0;i<lastElem+1;i++){
            printf("%d",array[i]);
            printf("%c",' ');
        }
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IDK, What is the goal of your `ptr+1=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));`?

Comment: Aside: drop the casts.  `int *ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));` is OK.  `int *ptr =  malloc(sizeof *ptr);` even better.

Comment: It's hard to explain, I am trying to do "
Stacks And Queues" and I want to allocate the "next part of the memory" with ptr+1, idk how to explain it tho.

Comment: I will put my code in the first post

Comment: `ptr` points to a singular `int` allocated on the stack.  Do not attempt to assign *anything* to `ptr + 1`, as that is not a space that has been allocated for you to do anything to it.

Comment: Okay, I will try something else

Comment: It looks like you need to brush up on arrays and dynamic allocation

Comment: I know how to do this without memory management , but I don't know how to do this with it

Comment: I think what you want is *realloc*. Google for *realloc stack*, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918690/using-realloc-on-a-stack

Comment: If you know how to do it without `malloc`, how about posting that working version so that we can understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Your code has several strange or dubious things about it which have nothing to do with `malloc`, by the way. Defining variables outside of `main` is one. `char action[6]` is not large enough to store `"remove"`, for another. Your compiler should issue a warning about `scanf("%s", &b)` and `printf("%d\n", ptr + i)` because the types are wrong; if it doesn't, you may need to turn up the warning level. Also read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](/q/605845/3650362)

Comment: I posted the code that doesn't use malloc

Comment: @ChristianGibbons - there should be a caveat on your comment. you can `realloc (ptr, 2 * sizeof *ptr)` and then you can assign to `*(ptr + 1)` (e.g. `ptr[1]`). You are correct you should not allocate and assign the new block to `ptr + 1` as that isn't a validly declared pointer.

Comment: The "working code" is broken, you call `free` on something that was not the result of malloc

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin By the time they attempt to assign a value to `ptr + 1`, `ptr` is pointing to an `int` on the stack rather than the original heap-allocation, so `realloc` would fail there, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fundamental and important issue. You need to not only know how to handle dynamic allocation, but how to handle it in the structured way. To begin with, you need two counters. One counter tracking the number of integers you have allocated for and the second counter tracking the number of integers used. You do not need to reallocate when you `"remove"` an integer, only when adding and when `used == allocated`. Otherwise, if `used < allocated`, there is no need to allocate for the next integer following `"add"`.

Ideally you want to allocate for some anticipated number of integers and only reallocate when you run out of space in the initially allocate block of memory (generally doubling the size of the currently allocated block each time reallocaion is needed) to minimize the number of relatively costly call to `realloc()`<sup>1</sup>. It does add a minor bit of complexity. For a learning exercise, allocating for each new `int` is fine.

One other note before looking at the allocation scheme is taking input with `scanf()`.  That leads to a horribly fragile input scheme. One stray character in input will result in a *matching-failure* where the bad character is left unread in `stdin` breaking your next (and if you rely on input ordering -- the rest of your) inputs. It is far better to read input with a *line-oriented* input function (like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) so that an entire line of input is consumed with each read. You can then parse the values you need from the buffer (character array) filled by `fgets()` using `sscanf()`. That way regardless of whether the conversion with `sscanf()` succeeds or fails, nothing is left unread in `stdin`.

Additionally, avoid the use of global variables. Instead, declare your variables in the scope where they are needed and then pass any needed information to a function as a parameter rather than relying on global variables. (they have their proper place -- but none you will find as you are learning C, unless you are programming on a microcontroller)

Now for your allocation scheme, changing your name of `number_of_elems` to `allocated` to track the number of integers allocated for and adding `used` to track the number of `int` used within your allocated block, your scheme would be:

- initialize `ptr = NULL;` to begin,
- after reading an `"add"` and using `strcmp()` to confirm (you compare string equality in C with `strcmp()`, not `==`), you will read and VALIDATE the conversion of the integer that follows, then
- compare `if (used == allocated)` to determine if allocation for a new integer is needed, if so
- use `realloc()` for all allocations (`realloc()` behaves like `malloc()` when the pointer is `NULL`),
- After you VALIDATE the allocation you increment `allocated += 1;` and after storing the integer value to the new block of memory, you increment `used += 1;`,
- if `"remove"` is chosen, all that is needed is you VALIDATE `used > 0` and if so, just decrement `used`, there is no need to adjust the allocation at this point -- that only happens with an `"add"`.
- [Optionally] after you read and `"add"`/`"remove"` loop completes, you can make one final `realloc()` to resize the allocated block of memory to just what is needed to store `used` number of integers.

So, how would you implement that? Let's' start with the declarations for `main()` initializing all variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256            /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main()
{
    /* avoid global variables, initialize all vars (good practice) */
    char action[MAXC] = "";             /* buffer (array) to hold every input */
    int allocated = 0,                  /* number of integers allocated */
        used = 0,                       /* number of integers used */
        *ptr = NULL;
```

Now let's look at your read loop and work through reading `action` and determining if we need to `"add"` a value:

```
    while (1) {
        int b = 0;      /* declare variables in scope needed */
        
        /* control read-loop with function return, end if EOF or [Enter] on empty-line */
        if (fgets (action, MAXC, stdin) == NULL || *action == '\n')
            break;
        action[strcspn (action, "\n")] = 0;         /* trim '\n' from end of action */
        
        if (strcmp (action, "add") == 0) {          /* compare strings with strcmp() */
            /* reused action to read integer value */
            if (!fgets (action, MAXC, stdin) || *action == '\n')
                break;
            
            if (sscanf (action, "%d", &b) != 1) {   /* validate conversion to int */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
```

At this point we have validated all inputs and all conversions and we know we need to `"add"` the value in `b` to our allocated block holding integers that we will assign to pointer. But note, since we are using `realloc()`, you ALWAYS `realloc()` to a temporary pointer so if `realloc()` fails returning `NULL`, you don't overwrite your pointer address with `NULL` creating a memory leak due to your loss of the address held by your pointer (which can now not be passed to `free()` to recover the memory). So when calling `realloc()` DO NOT do:

```
                ptr = realloc (ptr, size);
```

Instead DO:

```
                void *tmp = realloc (ptr, (allocated + 1) * sizeof *ptr);
                if (tmp == NULL) {                  /* validate EVERY allocation */
                    perror ("realloc-tmp");
                    break;                          /* don't exit, ptr still good */
                }
                ptr = tmp;                          /* assign reallocaed block to ptr */
```

It is only after validating the reallocation succeeds that you assign the newly allocate block of memory to your original pointer. If `realloc()` fails, the address for your original allocation in `ptr` is unchanged and still good, you can simply break at that point making use of all data stored to that point.

With that in mind, the rest of your `"add"` block is:

```
            /* realloc() behaves as malloc() if ptr is NULL, no need for separate malloc()
             * (realloc() using temporary pointer to avoid mem-leak if realloc() fails)
             */
            if (used == allocated) {
                void *tmp = realloc (ptr, (allocated + 1) * sizeof *ptr);
                if (tmp == NULL) {                  /* validate EVERY allocation */
                    perror ("realloc-tmp");
                    break;                          /* don't exit, ptr still good */
                }
                ptr = tmp;                          /* assign reallocaed block to ptr */
                allocated += 1;                     /* increment after validation */
            }
            
            ptr[used] = b;                          /* assing b to ptr at index */
            used += 1;                              /* increment after assignment */
            
            /* debug output - remove if desired */
            printf ("\nadding %d, used = %d, allocated = %d\n", b, used, allocated);
        }
```

Your `"remove"` block simply validates that you have integers to remove and then subtracts `1` from `used`. After the `if ... else if ...` block, then you can output the current contents of your allocated block that are used:

```
        else if (strcmp (action, "remove") == 0) {  /* ditto strmcp() */
            if (used > 0)                           /* only decrement used if > 0, and */
                used -= 1;                          /* (no need to adjust allocation)  */
            /* debug output, remove if desired */
            printf ("\nremove, used = %d, allocated = %d\n", used, allocated);
        }
        
        /* debug output (no need to duplicate in each if .. else ...) */
        puts ("\ncurrent content");
        for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
            printf ("%d\n", ptr[i]);
    }
```

Now, *Optionally* after your read loop completes you can resize your allocation to only the memory required to hold the integers `used`. This isn't mandatory, and usually isn't even necessary, but for completeness you could do:

```
    /* [optional] final realloc to resize to exact size needed for used integers */
    if (used < allocated) {
        void *tmp = realloc (ptr, used * sizeof *ptr);
        if (tmp)                                    /* validate reallocation */
            ptr = tmp;                              /* only assign after validation */
        else    /* otherwise just warn -- but original ptr still good */
            perror ("realloc-ptr-to-used");
    }
```

That is basically your program, the only thing that remains is using the stored values however you like and then calling `free (ptr);` when you are done to free the allocated memory. If you put it altogether, and outputting the complete list before freeing the allocated memory, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256            /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main()
{
    /* avoid global variables, initialize all vars (good practice) */
    char action[MAXC] = "";             /* buffer (array) to hold every input */
    int allocated = 0,                  /* number of integers allocated */
        used = 0,                       /* number of integers used */
        *ptr = NULL;
    
    while (1) {
        int b = 0;      /* declare variables in scope needed */
        
        /* control read-loop with function return, end if EOF or [Enter] on empty-line */
        if (fgets (action, MAXC, stdin) == NULL || *action == '\n')
            break;
        action[strcspn (action, "\n")] = 0;         /* trim '\n' from end of action */
        
        if (strcmp (action, "add") == 0) {          /* compare strings with strcmp() */
            /* reused action to read integer value */
            if (!fgets (action, MAXC, stdin) || *action == '\n')
                break;
            
            if (sscanf (action, "%d", &b) != 1) {   /* validate conversion to int */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            
            /* realloc() behaves as malloc() if ptr is NULL, no need for separate malloc()
             * (realloc() using temporary pointer to avoid mem-leak if realloc() fails)
             */
            if (used == allocated) {
                void *tmp = realloc (ptr, (allocated + 1) * sizeof *ptr);
                if (tmp == NULL) {                  /* validate EVERY allocation */
                    perror ("realloc-tmp");
                    break;                          /* don't exit, ptr still good */
                }
                ptr = tmp;                          /* assign reallocaed block to ptr */
                allocated += 1;                     /* increment after validation */
            }
            
            ptr[used] = b;                          /* assing b to ptr at index */
            used += 1;                              /* increment after assignment */
            
            /* debug output - remove if desired */
            printf ("\nadding %d, used = %d, allocated = %d\n", b, used, allocated);
        }
        else if (strcmp (action, "remove") == 0) {  /* ditto strmcp() */
            if (used > 0)                           /* only decrement used if > 0, and */
                used -= 1;                          /* (no need to adjust allocation)  */
            /* debug output, remove if desired */
            printf ("\nremove, used = %d, allocated = %d\n", used, allocated);
        }
        
        /* debug output (no need to duplicate in each if .. else ...) */
        puts ("\ncurrent content");
        for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
            printf ("%d\n", ptr[i]);
    }
    /* [optional] final realloc to resize to exact size needed for used integers */
    if (used < allocated) {
        void *tmp = realloc (ptr, used * sizeof *ptr);
        if (tmp)                                    /* validate reallocation */
            ptr = tmp;                              /* only assign after validation */
        else    /* otherwise just warn -- but original ptr still good */
            perror ("realloc-ptr-to-used");
    }
    
    printf ("\nfinal statistics and stored values\n"
            "  allocated : %d\n"
            "  used      : %d\n\n"
            "stored values :\n", allocated, used);
    for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
        printf ("%d\n", ptr[i]);
    
    free (ptr);     /* don't forget to free allocated memory */
}
```

**Example Input File**

Let's use an example input file (redirecting the file on `stdin` for program input) that exercises all parts of the program and includes garbage text that the program should ignore:

```
$ cat dat/add_remove.txt
alligators and other garbage
add
1 is the loneliest number that you ever knew.... (Three Dog Night)
add
2
add
3
add
4
remove
add
5
remove
remove
remove
remove
remove
add
6
add
7
remove
add
8
add
9
add
10
remove
```

This will add `1-10` and remove more integers than are stored at points and then pick up adding and removing more integers until all input is exhausted.

**Example Use/Output**

With the debug output shown in the code above the program output would be the following which at the end `6, 8, 9` are stored in your allocated block of memory:

```
$ ./bin/dyn_add_remove < dat/add_remove.txt

adding 1, used = 1, allocated = 1

current content
1

adding 2, used = 2, allocated = 2

current content
1
2

adding 3, used = 3, allocated = 3

current content
1
2
3

adding 4, used = 4, allocated = 4

current content
1
2
3
4

remove, used = 3, allocated = 4

current content
1
2
3

adding 5, used = 4, allocated = 4

current content
1
2
3
5

remove, used = 3, allocated = 4

current content
1
2
3

remove, used = 2, allocated = 4

current content
1
2

remove, used = 1, allocated = 4

current content
1

remove, used = 0, allocated = 4

current content

remove, used = 0, allocated = 4

current content

adding 6, used = 1, allocated = 4

current content
6

adding 7, used = 2, allocated = 4

current content
6
7

remove, used = 1, allocated = 4

current content
6

adding 8, used = 2, allocated = 4

current content
6
8

adding 9, used = 3, allocated = 4

current content
6
8
9

adding 10, used = 4, allocated = 4

current content
6
8
9
10

remove, used = 3, allocated = 4

current content
6
8
9

final statistics and stored values
  allocated : 4
  used      : 3

stored values :
6
8
9
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/dyn_add_remove < dat/add_remove.txt
==2698== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2698== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2698== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2698== Command: ./bin/dyn_add_remove
==2698==

current content

adding 1, used = 1, allocated = 1

current content
1
<snip>
final statistics and stored values
  allocated : 4
  used      : 3

stored values :
6
8
9
==2698==
==2698== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2698==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2698==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 5,172 bytes allocated
==2698==
==2698== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2698==
==2698== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2698== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

There is a lot of subtle detail here, so slow down and take the time to go through it and understand why each part of the program is structured the way it was. Specifically understand why the check of `if (used == allocated)` allows you to reduce the `"remove"` actions to a check and subtracting `1` from `used` following `else if (strcmp (action, "remove") == 0)`.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Footnotes:**

1. `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` have changed from moving the program break (with `brk`) to provide allocations through `memmap()` which has reduced the allocation penalty but has not eliminated it entirely. An efficient allocation scheme that balances the growth in the allocated block against the number of reallocation calls is still good practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your provided code.
Ex. In your main(), you allocated dynamic memory block to ptr. Assign address of integer "a" to "ptr" without free earlier memory assignment which creates memory leakage in your program.

The below program may clear your doubt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){

    // Create dynamic memory block and assign it to ptr integer pointer
    int *ptr=(int *)malloc(1 *sizeof(int));

    // Adding value in dynamic memory block
    *ptr=5;

    // Printing address ptr, address of dynamic memory block and its value
    printf("Pointer Address=%p, Memory Address=%p, Value=%d\n",&ptr, ptr, *ptr);

    // Left side value is not varaible. It is fix so it gives lvalue error, like assigning 1=2.
    //  ptr+1=(int *)malloc(1 *sizeof(int));

    // below ptr+1 indicate memory location which not allocated for this program
    printf("Unallocated Memory Address=%p\n",ptr+1);

    // Release memory which created as dynamic memory block
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Pointer Address=0x7ffc1e9a82c0, Memory Address=0x55a0d4a9e260, Value=5
Unallocated Memory Address=0x55a0d4a9e264
```

Comment: It is not necessary to cast the result of `malloc()` in C; in fact, it is idiomatic not to do so. It is also better to use expressions instead of explicit types as arguments to `malloc()`: `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);` This is easier to read, less to type, less error-prone and easier to maintain when code changes. And `malloc()` can fail; you must check the returned value to be sure that `malloc()` was successful, or risk undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> `ptr+1=(int*) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));`

This is not how you increase the size of the allocation held by `ptr`. After the first `malloc`, `ptr` contains the address of a 1-`int`-sized chunk of memory. `ptr + 1` is the address one-past-the-end of this chunk. Calling `malloc` a second time will return the address of *another* 1-`int`-sized block of memory. But you can't make them adjacent by assigning one to the other, just like you can't write `2 + 1 = 4;` and break the universe.

Instead you have to request that the chunk held by `ptr` be *resized*. You do this with the `realloc` function. Here's a program that does what I think you were trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int length = 1; // initial length of the array
    int *array = malloc(length * sizeof *array);
    array[0] = 1;

    while (1) {
        char action;
        scanf("%c", &action);

        if (action == 'a') {
            int newElem;
            scanf("%d", &newElem);

            // grow the array by 1
            array = realloc(array, (length + 1) * sizeof *array);
            array[length] = newElem;
            length += 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                printf("%d ", array[i]);
            }
        }
        if (action == 'r') {
            // shrink the array by 1
            array = realloc(array, (length - 1) * sizeof *array);
            length -= 1;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                printf("%d ", array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that:

- `realloc` can return a *different* pointer than the one passed to it. This means that there was not enough heap space to resize the chunk, so the data was copied to a new chunk and the old one has been freed. This is why you should assign the result back to `array`. You must not use the old value of `array` after `realloc`ing it.
- This program has undefined behavior if `realloc` (or `malloc`) fails.
- Growing and shrinking the array by 1 each time is quite inefficient. It's much more common, and faster, to allocate more memory than you need and grow it by large chunks, using a third variable to keep track of the array's total capacity (distinct from the length).
- [Don't cast the return value of `malloc` and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3650362)

Comment: @IDK Please upvote good answers, and if one of them solved your problem mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark. (If multiple answers answer the question, you should pick the one you like best, or the one that most helped you; don't feel pressured to accept mine). Marking answers accepted lets other people know that you are no longer looking for an answer. Thank you and welcome to Stack Overflow!